# Xcode 10 unexpected duplicate task: CopyPlistFile

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, plist, tvos, xcode10

Today I updated my Xcode from v.9.4.1 to v.10.0. Now I try to build my tvOS project and I see the following error: **unexpected duplicate task: CopyPlistFile /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication/Build/Products/Debug-appletvos/MyApplication.app/Settings.plist /Users/username/project_folder/Settings.plist (in target 'MyApplicationTarget')**. I tried to reinstall pods (I use CocoaPods 1.6.0 beta) and clean build folder, but it does not help. How can I solve this problem in Xcode 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project.pbxproj file I had these lines:

```
FIRSTSTRING /* Settings.plist in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = FIRSTSTRING /* Settings.plist */; };
SECONDSTRING /* Settings.plist in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = SECONDSTRING /* Settings.plist */; };
```

As I can see Settings.plist was specified twice in this file, as source and resource.

I removed Settings.plist from my project and added it again in **Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources**. Now I see that the lines I mentioned above are missing and I have this line in my project.pbxproj file:

```
THIRDSTRING /* Settings.plist in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = THIRDSTRING /* Settings.plist */; };
```

And now I am able to build my tvOS application with Xcode 10.0.

Answer (score 19):

I was getting this for a core data model .xcdatamodeld,  It turned out the model file was listed under both "Compile Sources" & "Copy Bundle resources" in Build Phases.   Removed it from the latter and it build in Xcode 10 finally!

Comment: You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 18):

Faced same problem. Resolved it using following

```
go to Target -> Build Phases
```

Check if your file is appearing in both **Compile sources** and **Copy Bundle Resources** section, if yes remove it from **Compile Sources**

Answer (score 13):

File -> Workspace Settings -> Change New Build System to Legacy.
It worked for me .

Comment: In newer versions of Xcode this is changing:  **File > Project Settings > New Build System** to **File > Project Settings > Legacy**

Answer (score 9):

In my case, the conflicting files were not listed in **Copy Bundle Resources** but only in **Compile Sources** section.

I went in project navigator, selected the file, and in **File Inspector / Target Membership** unselected and again selected the app target (untick and tick checkbox next to app target).

The files disappeared from 'Compile Sources' and appeared under 'Copy Bundle Resources' and I was able to continue with the build process.

Comment: I use my own pod in my apps and did this untick -> tick for a while when i was building versions of my app. I now found the problem my file was not in the Resources folder putting it there solved the problem permanently. Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Go look at that target’s build phase that copies resource files and see if your Settings.plist is listed more than once.

Comment: This file is listed only once in MyApplicationTarget/Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: I assume you also tried quitting Xcode, deleting DerivedData folder, and then relaunching Xcode?

Comment: I deleted the DerivedData folder, relaunched Xcode 10, cleaned build folder, but error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

if using firebase then
delete GoogleService-Info and add agin in project
It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

When working with Unity game engine for building an iOS project, I came across this same problem.

I've noticed that this always happens when I change the build type from Release To Development and then make Unity build the app in the **same** build folder. When I keep the output build folders for release and development builds separate for iOS, this problem does not happen - I think because Xcode believes they are separate projects.